# In VBA, VLOOKUP into closed file tries to open file

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I'm trying to create a vlookup between two workbooks. One of them is open (checkWkbk) and the other one is closed (cms). This code seems to work, but it pops up a window "Update Values: cms" where I have to select the file set in the cms variable. Is there a way to do this without that window popping up (i.e., just completing the vlookup without me having to find and select that file)?

Here's my code:

```
Dim checkWkbk As Workbook, cms As Workbook
Dim exportSheet As Worksheet, dupeSheet As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long

'stuff happens here. exportSheet and dupeSheet 
'are both sheets in checkWkbk, so there's some 
'copying of columns and whatnot that happens before the vlookup    

Set cms = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\owner\Documents\allAssets.xlsx")

'activate checkWkbk and dupesheet
checkWkbk.Activate
dupeSheet.Select

With ActiveSheet
    lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(lr, 3)).FormulaR1C1 = _
       "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2], cms!C1:C2, 2, FALSE)"
End With

cms.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Thanks in advance for the help! I'm very new to VBA so please let me know if I can better explain the question...

Comment: (a) Try setting `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` (and set it back to `True` at the end of the code).  (b) The `cms!` in your `VLookup` function is telling Excel to look in columns B and C of sheet "cms" in the workbook in which the active sheet is located - it is **not** telling Excel to look in your VBA code for a variable defined as `cms` when the code was last run, work out which workbook that was pointing to at the time, guess which sheet you meant to refer to, and then do a VLookup on that range.  So I think you may need to rethink your approach.

Comment: (b) (cont)  The approach you use will be quite different depending on whether you need to keep a formula in those cells, or whether you are happy to place values into those cells based on what was contained in `allAssets.xlsx` at the time the macro was run.  (a) (cont) Ignore (a) - I was thinking the message might be coming up as the file was being opened, but it is undoubtedly complaining about the missing sheet in your `VLookup`, so whatever you do to fix (b) will automatically get rid of the message.